# JS Вывести из массива элементы по очереди

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как исправить.
Есть массив и нужно вывести каждый элемент по очереди и записать его в параграф при нажатии на кнопку.
Нажал на кнопку, вывелось в параграф "идти". Нажал еще раз вывелось "бежать", "идти" пропало. Нажал 3 раз выводится след элемент "спать" и т.д.

```js
function f1() {
  var ru = ['идти', 'бежать', 'спать'];
  var p = document.getElementById('ru')
  for (var i = 0; i < ru.length; i++) {
    p.innerHTML = ru[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="ru"> </p>
<button onclick="f1()">Push</button>
```

У меня выводится не по очереди, а только последний элемент массива.

Comment: А после спать - по кругу?

Comment: p.innerHTML += ru[i];

Comment: @haswell `Нажал еще раз вывелось "бежать", "идти" ПРОПАЛО`, не нужно все подряд выводить.

Comment: Я так понял, нужно где-то хранить индекс элемента массива, который выводится в данный момент, чтоб при последующем нажатии на основе этого индекса вывести следующее значение массива, все верно?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 0;
var ru = ['идти','бежать', 'спать'];
var p = document.getElementById('ru')
function f1() {
      p.innerHTML = ru[i++];
      i = i % 3
  }
```

```html
<p id="ru"> </p>
<button onclick="f1()">Push</button>
```

Comment: остаток от целочисленного деления на 3

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ru = ['идти', 'бежать', 'спать'];

function f1() {
  document.getElementById('ru').textContent = action.next().value;
}

let action = gen();

function* gen(i = 0) {
  while (true) {
    yield ru[i++ % 3];
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="ru"> </p>
<button onclick="f1()">Push</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почти тоже самое, но с хранением индекса в data атрибуте

```
function changeContent() {
    var ru = ['идти', 'бежать', 'спать'];
    var p = document.getElementById('p');
    var index = p.getAttribute("data-index") || 0;
    p.innerHTML = ru[index];
    index++;
    index = ru[index] ? index : 0;
    p.setAttribute("data-index", index);
}
```